# How can I just print a single object and not it's children?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, data-modeling

My goal is to allow users to modify the elements of an object that are within a list of other objects. To first do this, I need to search for the element "name" so that I can identify the specific object with that name that needs to be modified. My code does the job to a point, however, I have 3 objects, and 2 of those objects are "nested" within one. So I'm in the predicament whereby if I search for the parent object, it shows me the result of the parent object and it's child objects and if I search for the child object, it returns null. How can I fix this so that it only returns the specific object with the element name that I searched for? I'd like to treat each of them individually.

1. The format of the xml cannot be changed for this, since the structure is what I'm limited to

> I'm not sure if the problem came about with how I originally parsed the xml file into java objects

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        File file = new File("items.xml");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Items itemData = (Items) un.unmarshal(file);

        List<Item> items = itemData.getItem();

        System.out.println("'\n\n------------- Options ---------------");
        System.out.println("\n1. Search Items by Group");
        System.out.println("\n2. Modify Movie");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if (choice == 2){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the movie you would like to modify: ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            Optional<Item> item = items.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
                    .findFirst();

            System.out.println(item.toString());

        }

        else{
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid option!");
        }
    }
}
```

Item class

```
public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
    }
}
```

Items class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<items> 
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Rush Hour</name>
            <data>1</data>
            <group>Comedy</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter</name>
            <data>2</data>
            <group>Fiction</group>
            <items>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter and the Goblet Of Fire</name>
                        <data>3</data>
                        <group>Fiction</group>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter and the Chamber of secrets</name>
                        <data>4</data>
                        <group>Fiction</group>
                  </item>
            </items>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Men In Black</name>
            <data>5</data>
            <group>Action</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Coming to America</name>
            <data>6</data>
            <group>Comedy</group>
      </item>
</items>
```

Comment: what is `private Items items;`, you want this as list of items something like this `private List<Item> items;`.

Comment: I have the list in another class. I'll update my post to show said class also.

Comment: just remove items from your toString, or add a second method to return that value without items

Comment: @Stultuske the toString helps with printing the child objects, since without it the child items would not print.

Comment: @SharleneRoberts and since you want to print it without the "child" items, that's a bit the point. Or, as I said: if you want to keep the items in the toString, create a second method that returns a String, and print that where you don't want the items to be printed

Comment: @Stultuske   Would this suffice?
 
`public String singleObject(){
        return
              "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
              "\n\tName: " + name +
              "\n\tData: " + data +
              "\n\tGroup: " + group;
    }`

Comment: if you call it where it needs to be called, yes

Comment: I'm calling it in the main method where `System.out.println(item.toString());` was, however it's giving me an unresolved method and I'm not sure why

Comment: You need to search recursively. Now you searching only top level elements.

Comment: unresolved method? on what type? on what line? toString can not possibly cause unresolved method, since it's inherited from Object. Also: System.out.println(item.toString()); is the same as System.out.println(item);

Comment: No, I replaced `System.out.println(item.toString());` with `System.out.println(item.singleObject());` since singleObject was the newly created method. I got the error for singleObject being the unresolved method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to search the nested item as well. Please take help from below code:

```
            Optional<Item> item = items.stream()
                .map(x->{
                    if(x.getItems()==null){
                        return Collections.singletonList(x);
                    }
                    x.getItems().getItem().add(x);
                    return x.getItems().getItem();
                })
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
                .peek(x-> x.setItems(null))//Peek exists mainly to support debugging
                .findFirst();
```

which will help to search elements in **2 levels nested** object.

When you search **Harry Potter and the Chamber of secrets** then it will give a single item of **Harry Potter** object mapping that name.

```
Optional[
    DataType: Number
    Name: Harry Potter and the Chamber of secrets
    Data: 4
    Group: Fiction
    Items: null
]
```

Comment: For this post, this answer isn't what I'm looking for since like I mentioned `I'd like to treat each of them individually.`

Comment: Okay, then you can use flatMap with some twist. Please refer the updated answer.